# Passing path to function makes Get-ChildItem return more files

Tags: powershell

I have a simple command which lists all files in the scriptfolder

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    Write-Host $file
}
```

It gives me the following output:

```
PS C:\Users\ivu> D:\jenkins\workspace\DeploymentInstaller\usemod.ps1
functions.psm1
installClient.ps1
installClientParams.ps1
usemod.ps1
```

**Question:**
Now the behaviour which i can not explain happens, when I wrap the code by a function and a filter `Get-ChildItem` suddenly returns much more files. 
Can someone explain this behaviour?

```
Function funct($path, $regex){
    Write-Host $path
    Write-Host $regex

    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter $regex
    foreach ($file in $files)
    {
        Write-Host $file
    }
}
funct($PSScriptRoot, "*")
```

Output

```
PS C:\Users\ivu> D:\jenkins\workspace\DeploymentInstaller\usemod.ps1
functions.psm1
installClient.ps1
installClientParams.ps1
usemod.ps1
C:\Users\ivu\.dbvis
C:\Users\ivu\.eclipse
C:\Users\ivu\.squirrel-sql
C:\Users\ivu\.swt
C:\Users\ivu\Citrix
C:\Users\ivu\Contacts
C:\Users\ivu\Desktop
C:\Users\ivu\Documents
C:\Users\ivu\Downloads
C:\Users\ivu\faab
C:\Users\ivu\Favorites
C:\Users\ivu\Links
C:\Users\ivu\Music
C:\Users\ivu\Pictures
C:\Users\ivu\Saved Games
C:\Users\ivu\Searches
C:\Users\ivu\Tracing
C:\Users\ivu\transfer
C:\Users\ivu\Videos
C:\Users\ivu\workspace
C:\Users\ivu\.jboss-cli-history
C:\Users\ivu\bla.txt
C:\Users\ivu\Icc.state
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the function incorrectly. By using a comma in the arguments you actually end up passing an array, so you're basically saying:

```
Get-ChildItem D:\jenkins\workspace\DeploymentInstaller
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\ivu
```

If you were to call as follows, you'll get the expected result:

```
funct $PSScriptRoot "*"
```

And I say **"expected result"** as in that will list the files at

`D:\jenkins\workspace\DeploymentInstaller`

because the script you're calling is in that directory and thus `$PSScriptRoot` will contain that value.